# JSON format of data

Tags: javascript, json, database, sqlite, database-design

How many formats a data can travel in, other than JSON format, i was reading Mongodb it says

> Node.js and MongoDB are a pair made for each other. Being able to use JSON across the board and JavaScript makes development very easy.

I was wondering How many other data format data travel between server and client or from client to the server

Comment: XML is another option...but it depends on your requirements and design..

Comment: what about sql what format it saves data and send when requested

Comment: AFAIK, most of the servers nowadays rely on HTTP protocol and REST api and use JSON for to and fro communication with clients...

Answer (score 0):

xml, yaml,Gellish, REBOL, Atom, RDF are some of the other formats you can use. However json and xml have always stood out when it comes to data exchange.

I would however advise that you stick with json as its supported in most technologies and there lots of documentation online about json. Using Rest services will also be a lot easier with json.

xml would be your next best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this question is kinda a how long is a piece of string?

XML and JSON are standard. HTML is an extended version of xml for instance. As in the other answers. There are a lot of different ways of sending data. The only important thing is that the sender and the receiver speak the same protocol.

There are also binary protocols which don't send things in plain text and are more specifically designed.

My current favorite is dson. Or doge-son.
https://github.com/dogescript/DSON